# Excel vba detect when any control form is clicked

Tags: excel, vba, events, radio-button

I have a random number of radio buttons created dynamically according to table data. These buttons are all inside a Frame and each is individually named. What event controller or such do I use in order to detect which button has been clicked? I've put them all into the same 'GroupName'. I've tried groupname_click(), frame1_click(), mousedown_event detect. I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You could look at using a control array - see for example: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/15/vba-control-arrays/

Comment: That looks very promising. Thank you

Comment: Are these radio buttons placed on a sheet? Have a look at the Cell link

Comment: Tim's link was the perfect fix. 100% successful and answered exactly what I needed.

Comment: The radiobuttons are part of a userform